# hardhat test: <functionName> is not a function

Tags: blockchain, solidity, hardhat

i'm testing my contracts on hardhat network with fork of BSC.

i'm deploying my token contract that have mint function:

```
// @dev Creates `_amount` token to `_to`. Must only be called by the owner (MasterChef).
function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) public onlyOwner {
    _mint(_to, _amount);
    _moveDelegates(address(0), _delegates[_to], _amount);
}
```

then i'm deploying it on test using `> npx hardhat test`, it will run tests of this code:

```
...
it("Should deploy", async () => {
        token = await Token.deploy();
        await token.deployed();
        console.debug(`\t\t\tToken Contract Address: ${cyan}`, token.address);
        const supply = await token.totalSupply()
        console.debug(`\t\t\tToken totalSupply: ${yellow}`, supply);
        await token.mint(owner.address, web3.utils.toWei("1000", 'ether'))
        console.debug(`\t\t\tToken owner balance: ${cyan}`, token.balanceOf(owner.address));
 });
 ...
```

test print the first 2 console debug **correctly**:

```
 Token Contract Address: 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3
 Token totalSupply: 0
```

also `token.totalSupply()` works, so the token is deployed correctly, but when it have to call `token.mint()` it give this error:

```
 TypeError: token.mint is not a function
  at Context.<anonymous> (test/general.js:102:21)
  at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

i tried to clean all the artifacts running `> npx hardhat clean` and delated all the cache, but i still have the error

Comment: Is the `mint()` function part of the `contract Token` or of another contract (e.g. an imported library) in the set of your contracts?

Comment: @PetrHejda `mint()` is part of the `contract Token`, as you can see, inside `mint()` there is `_mint()` that is part of BEP20 imported contract, there isn't any other `mint()` function

Answer (score 18, accepted):

if you declared two mint functions then you have to explicitly use the fully qualified signature.
Example:

```
token["mint(address,uint256)"](owner.address, web3.utils.toWei("1000", 'ether'))
```

I found the solution here
https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/407

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score -1):

**functionName is not a function** this error occurs if the function is not available in your smart contract. in your case the function name is not  mint() it's _mint().

Comment: as you can see in the question, in the contract i have the mint() function ( first code in the question)

Answer (score -1):

in `beforeEach()` block of code get your contract object by -

`const token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token")`

If you haven't defined `beforeEach()` block define it before `it()` block

```
  beforeEach(async function () {
    Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token")
    token = await token.deploy()
  })
```

define `Token` and `token` using `let` keyword before, also somewhere in your code you may be missing `await` somewhere so that could be also the reason. Thanks.